# How to avoid PHP Warning for Undefined Offset in wp-db.php using foreach

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm attempting to set a cookie containing a post ID, but only when the current post ID isn't present in a table. The code works, but I'm getting a PHP warning "Undefined offset: 0" from wp-includes/wp-db.php and I'm wondering what I've done wrong.

```
function getFromDatabase() {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT page_id FROM foo WHERE page_id IS NOT NULL" );
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
    $resultsArray = array();
    foreach ( $result as $row ) {
        $resultsArray[] = $row->page_id;
    }
    return $resultsArray;
}

...

$currentPID = get_the_id();
$ignoredPIDs = getFromDatabase();
if ( !in_array($currentPID, $ignoredPIDs) ) {
    // Set a cookie to post ID
}
```

I should mention that the DB query will always return at least one result. Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

**Update** - Found the problem, it was the call to `$wpdb->prepare`. It's just a guess, but nothing needed preparing, everything is hard-coded, and perhaps it was complaining about that.

Comment: The error should include a line number as well. There doesn't seem to be any problems in the code you've supplied. But somewhere you are trying to access the 0'th element of an empty array (maybe the result of `getFromDatabase()` if it's empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to see what's in getFromDatabase:

I know you said that the DB query will always return at least one result but just for the heck of it, try to check for empty. If this works then your problem is obviously in the getFromDatabase function.

```
$currentPID = get_the_id();
$ignoredPIDs = getFromDatabase();
if(!empty($ignoredPIDs)) {
  if ( !in_array($currentPID, $ignoredPIDs) ) {
      // Set a cookie to post ID
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that didn't fix it, but the problem is definitely within the getFromDatabase function. The function returns an array, and if instead of running the SQL query, I just define the array and return it, I don't get the warning. It's definitely something to do with the way that I'm querying the DB and organizing the results to return, but I'm not sure how I messed up.

Comment: You might want to post the code for the getFromDatabase function if you need additional help from the knowledgeable people on the stack.